# how to call .sql function at matlab?

Tags: sql, matlab

I wrote code in linqpad and saved it as test.sql
Then I want to call the query from matlab. what should I do?
someone suggest to use result=runsqlscript(connect,'test.sql') 
but it didn't work. the function runsqlscript does not exist in matlab.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the above that this is the easiest method, check version and use database toolbox. Add that an easy "check" on the call to script is to use the interface to connect to your data and on the import data button use the drop down "generate sql script" to build a Matlab "wrapper" for your sql. Is useful if error msg seems ambiguous